# tty.setraw on pseudoterminal hangs in OS X

Tags: python, macos, posix, pty

This is a code snippet that works perfectly fine on a Ubuntu system, but calling setraw on OS X makes the Python process hang.

```py
import os, sys, termios, tty

# Open pseudo terminal
m,s = os.openpty()
stdin = os.fdopen(s, 'r', 0)
stdout = os.fdopen(s, 'w', 0)

# Remember olt attrs for restoration later on
tcattr = termios.tcgetattr(stdin.fileno())

# Set pseudo terminal in raw mode
tty.setraw(stdin.fileno())

# Write something on the slave side of the pseudo terminal
stdout.write('test\n')

# Call setraw again. (for no reason) But it hangs here...
tty.setraw(stdin.fileno())
```

Is there something wrong with this code, or does OS X behave differently? It used to work in the past, but some subtle change in our code made it block in OS X now...